# How to retain comment text on comment form after login/registration?

Tags: comments, login, user-registration, comment-form

When users type some comment text and then click the login/register/sociallogin button next to the comment textarea and it registers them, it then redirects to the same page and totally **erases** their comment.

This is a terrible user experience and I need to retain the comment of the user on redirect! I noticed that if a user posts an anonymous comment wordpress remembers their last typed name and email, so having this happen for the comment form would be perfect.

So that way, user clicks register and it registers and logs them in, but repopulates the comment textarea with their comment they were typing before login.

How can I do this so the user does not lose the comment when they register?